# jQuery modal execution meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a jQuery modal I'm trying to execute in meteor, code as follows:

```
<template name="groupsList">
<div class="noGroups">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      ...
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg modal-toggle">
        Create a Group
      </button>
    </div>
</div>

{{> createGroup}}
</template>
```

---

```
<template name="createGroup">
    <div class="modal fade" id="createGroupModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Create!" class="btn btn-primary modal-toggle"/>
    ...
    </div>
</template>
```

When I add the jQuery to the top level code it works fine, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".modal-toggle").click(function () {
        $('#createGroupModal').modal('toggle');
    });
</script>
```

However I'd like to move it to a .js file. The js file I'm using is located in the same directory as the HTML I'm loading. I feel like I need to use Template.events here, so I tried this, but the bind does not seem to happen, as nothing happens when I click the button:

```
Template.groupsList.events({
    'click .modal-toggle': function(){
        $('#createGroupModal').modal('toggle');
    }
});
```

What am I missing? What is the proper Meteor way to do this?

Comment: A previous project, in pre-Meteor-0.9, had an object literal `Template.something.events = {'click #blahId': function(){ do_something(); } }`.   I see the [recent docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events) show `Template.something.events(eventMap)` as a function taking the literal eventMap object instead.  I wonder if there has been a change and if that matters for you.

Comment: Insert `console.log("in click handler");` as the first line of the anonymous function in the eventMap.  Fire up the app, look in the browser for the console.log message when pushing the button.  That will at least let us know if that code is being reached.  Also, are there any errors or messages in the browser console log?

Comment: Also, pop open the browser console.log, and try looking for your template's eventMap in `Template.groupsList.__eventMaps[0]` by typing that expression into the console.

Comment: The console log is indeed not appearing on click, so I suppose the event handling itself is wrong as well. Will dig into this a bit more and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Issue in one of my template names, can't believe how many cycles I burned staring at the screen.